# apache2.2 virtual host rewrite rule not matching

Tags: mod-rewrite, pattern-matching, apache2.2

I have a very simple rewrite rule in a virtual host:

```
RewriteRule ^/?([^.]+)\.([^(htm)]+)$ /$1.htm [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/(someotherrule)$ /me [L]
```

Say a call a url: `http://myurl.com/test.php`

I would expect the the rule to match and the url to be rewritten to `http://myurl.com/test.htm`

Instead I find this in my rewriteLog:

```
applying pattern '^/?([^.]+)\\.([^(htm)]+)$' to uri '/test.php'
applying pattern '^/(someotherrule)$' to uri '/test.php'
rewrite '/test.php' -> '/me'
```

Obviously there is something wrong with my first rewrite rule pattern, but I cannot see what exactly. Probably because I have a knot in my brain from lack of sleep. So if someone would be kind enough to take a second and point out my error, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace the first rule, resulting in:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^[^.]+\.htm$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?([^.]+)\..*$ /$1.htm [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^/(someotherrule)$ /me [L]
```

Error is in **[^(htm)]**, meaning that the file extension does not contain characters: (, h, t, m,) , not .htm as you expected.